# Updating variables automatically in multiple classes

Tags: python

Certain objects are immutable in Python, meaning you can't change them. To get around this, I'm thinking about implementing a solution where I provide a memory location instead of a variables.

Here's an example of the undesirable behavior.

Example of undesirable behavior

```
x = y = lambda x: x
x(1)
# 1 out
y(1)
# 1 out
y = lambda x: 2*x
y(1)
# 2 out
x(1)
# 1 out
```

Example of behavior that I'd like to have.

```
CACHE = {"f": lambda x:x}
class Foo:
      def __init__(self, func):
           self.func = func

      def __call__(self, x):
           return self.func['f'](x)

foo = foo2 = Foo(CACHE)

foo(1)
# output 1
foo2(1)
# output 1

CACHE['f'] = lambda x: 2*x
foo(1)
# output 2
foo(2)
# output 2 <-- now it's 2
```

Is there a solution to this that is less of a cludge?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you think that achieves, but you have at least one typo - `"_init__" != "__init__"`

Comment: Objects are immutable?? what do mean here and what are u trying to achieve..

Comment: Python has managed memory. To get the memory address of a python object you would need to a use a C library for low level access. Also remember that immutable objects tend to be immutable for a reason (ie. security and thread safety): https://hackernoon.com/5-benefits-of-immutable-objects-worth-considering-for-your-next-project-f98e7e85b6ac

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry about that. Should be good now!

Comment: @Mike67 This for a simple solo app that doesn't talk to any servers so I'm not too worried about security. I was doing some reading online and I think what I need is the "Observer Pattern"

Comment: Why dont u have a class variable, which is not tied to an object.. that solves the whole problem!!

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran Do you mean make func it's own class, pass that class as a parameter, and then make modifications to that class?

Comment: Nope.. added a answer.. pls check

Comment: "To get around this, I'm thinking about implementing a solution where I provide a memory location instead of a variables" That doesn't make any sense. Python provides no public way to access object by their memory location, and in general, that isn't how yo should be thinking about things. In any case, it is unclear what your problem is, `foo2(1)`  returns `2`, not `1` in your first example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `foo2(1)` -> `2`. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually trying to achieve is to have some function pointer which is common to all the objects whose definition you can modify on the fly..

Add a class variable which holds the function and call it from the **Call** method

```
In [6]:
   ...:
   ...: class Foo:
   ...:     func = None
   ...:     def __call__(self, x):
   ...:         return Foo.func(x)
   ...:

In [7]: Foo.func=lambda x:x*2

In [8]: f=f1=Foo()

In [9]: f(1)
Out[9]: 2

In [10]: f1(2)
Out[10]: 4

In [11]: Foo.func=lambda x:x

In [12]: f(1)
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: f1(2)
Out[13]: 2
```

Infact python allows you overwrite function definitions on the fly like this. But i wouldnt prefer to do that:

```
In [19]: class A:
    ...:     def __call__(self, x):
    ...:         return self.func(x)
    ...:     def func(self, x):
    ...:         return x
    ...:

In [20]:

In [20]: a=A()

In [21]: a(1)
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: A.func =  lambda x:x*2

In [24]: A.func =  lambda self, x:x*2

In [25]:

In [25]: a(2)
Out[25]: 4
```